# gif loading image not working in jquerymoblie

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, loading, gif

We get Data for Local `SqLiteDB`.And then We display data into `ListView`.But it's taking some time.So We need `loadingMessage` Like this 
[image]

We tried like this

```
$('#content').append('<img src="../images/Loading_Animation.gif" alt="US Flag" "/>');
```

but no luck .Please any one guide  to me .Please any one tell me if any other best approach

Comment: How do you retrieve data from database? can you share your code?

Comment: @Omar jest i am using select query and then get result that is not problem i have 600 records so it's taking some time.So in this time we placed some effect .if have any thing know about my problem plz help me

Comment: You can use `$.mobile.loading("show")` and `"hide"` to show jQM loading spinner. That's why I've asked when/how do fetch data from server? Are you using Ajax or other methods?

Comment: [This works](http://jsfiddle.net/r1fvoqz8/16/), so may be issue with where you place code, or image location. Check that.

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ thanks it's work on browser but when i check into mobile it's not work

Comment: Is that opened in webview?

Comment: @Omar i tried as you said but no luck

Comment: try to use jquery mobile loading widget ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope it will work

```
   **HTML**

   //hide image where do you want to show
   <img src="filename.gif" id="loadinggif" style="display:none">

   **JQuery**

   //before ajax call show gif image

   $("#loadinggif").show();

   $.ajax({
     url: 'filename.php',
     type: 'POST',
     success: function(data) {

       //after ajax success hide gif

       $("#loadinggif").hide();     

       console.log(data);

     }

   });
```